# How can I change the monitor resolution on a Banana Pro?

Tags: banana-pi

I'd like to change the resolution of my monitor, connected via HDMI from a Banana Pro.

I get a list of available monitor resolutions by the following command:

```
cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/modes
```

and then pick one of them that I want to use, say:

```
D:1280x720p-50
```

(1280x720p, 50 Hz refresh rate)

I've edited the /etc/rc.local file to include

```
echo D:1280x720p-50 > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode
```

Saved the file, rebooted - no change from the default resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out with a bit of tinkering.

Remove the SD card with the linux image on it, and stick it into a computer that can read it.

Open up the uEnv.txt file to edit it.

Change this

```
disp.screen0_output_mode=EDID:1280x720p50
```

to this

```
disp.screen0_output_mode=1280x720p50
```

The EDID argument tells the kernel to try and use the monitor's settings to determine a resolution. Removing it forces your selected resolution to be used.

For some reason, this defaulted to a really low resolution for my screen with the Banana Pro.